How to configure the existed Qt Libraries?
I am working on embedding the video in WebEngineView in QML and Qt. With the existing configuration, the WebEngineView can not show the type of the video (Twitch live video). I guess it is because WebEngineView does not support this type.
This is my code and the result when I try to embed the Twitch Video.
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineProfile>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QNetworkCookie>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
    QWebEngineView * view = new QWebEngineView(window);
    QWebEngineProfile * profile = new QWebEngineProfile(view);
    window->setCentralWidget(view);
    window->resize(1024, 768);
    window->show();

    QWebEnginePage * page = new QWebEnginePage(profile, view);
    view->setPage(page);
    view->load(QUrl("https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=IncredulousAbstemiousFennelImGlitch&parent=streamernews.example.com&parent=embed.example.com"));

    return app.exec();
}



So how to configure the WebEngineView library to support this type of the video? Or is there anyway to make it work without re-configuration?

Playing multimedia content is never guaranteed to work "out of the box" and often requires further efforts, including the possibility of supporting third party codecs (which may be limited by licenses) or DRM aspects. Multimedia management is a quite difficult subject, especially when dealing with frameworks (and related licenses issues). You cannot expect any audio or video to work anywhere just with a few lines of code.

After searching and trying multiple times with more complicated code, I think that I will config the WebEngineView to support the codecs to show live video on Twitch but I don't know how to do.
